# Check if CDATA is necessary using Regex

Tags: regex, xml, symfony, twig

I need to write an xml in twig.

The xml will contain elements with and without HTML or special characters.

To keep the xml more readable I want only to add CDATA escaping when it is necassary.

Is there any regex to check for example the following strings if cdata is needed

```
 <p>Test<p>     : CDATA needed   
 Test124        : CDATA not needed  
 /de/test123    : CDATA not needed
```

Note: can't use html entities because the reader doesn't support this so the twig autoescape function will not fix my problem.

Comment: You only wish to CDATA escape HTML entities? Can you exhaustively define for us what you mean by **special data**, please.

Comment: I only want to add cdata when its necassery eg. html or other special data

Comment: So you're only looking for this I guess: `[<&]` - or use `[<>&]` just in case

Comment: thx think that should do the job